# Replace Phaser with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future, phaser

I have a bunch of methods using `Phaser` (with always 1 party) and I could  replace each method by using `CompletableFuture` instead. The result would be the same. Are there any hidden benefits when using `CompletableFuture`?

For example:

**version 1 with CompletableFuture:**

```
void queryVersion1() {
    var future = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
    asyncCall(future);
    future.join();
}

void asyncCall(CompletableFuture<Void> future){
    ...
    future.complete(null);
}
```

**version 2 with Phaser:**

```
void queryVersion2() {
    var phaser = new Phaser(1);
    asyncCall(phaser);
    phaser.awaitAdvance(0);
}

void asyncCall(Phaser phaser){
    ...
   phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
}
```

Which one should I prefer and why? Which one performs better in terms of memory/thread pool/etc.

Comment: Readability? Though I don't know what the two versions of your code look like as you don't provide an example.

Comment: No in my case, both have good readability. I mean difference in terms of performance (object creation overhead, synchronization overhead,..). I think phaser is more lightweight than CompletableFeature, the same as CoundDownLatch is more lightweight than CompletableFuture, or?

Comment: Could you show an example of using both? I would expect `Phaser` to be blocking while `CompletableFuture` may not be. But I don't have much experience with `Phaser` so I'm not sure how you might be using it.

Comment: @Slaw yes, phaser will block and I actually have one problem when replacing my phaser code with CompletableFuture (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60363317/completablefuture-and-thread-currentthread-interrupt): The calls of two CompletableFuture methods seem not be isolated from each other. With phaser I do not have such troubles. So I stick to phaser.

Comment: Maybe one difference, but I am not sure: CompletableFuture uses default ExecutorService (also for blocking code) while CoundDownLatch/Phaser does not need an ExecutorService behind, or?

Comment: I think the executor of CompletableFuture is only used for Async calls, but not for blocking calls..

Comment: It's a little more nuanced than that. I recommend reading the class documentation of [`CompletionStage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) and [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) to understand more about how stages are triggered and what threads are used. But methods like `CompletableFuture#join()` and `CompletableFuture#get()` will block the _calling_ thread.

Comment: I only use `CompletableFuture#join()`, `CompletableFuture#complete()` and `CompletableFuture#completeOnTimeout` to replace the phasers. So only the latter makes use of CompletableFuture's executor service.

Comment: Be careful about how you use the `orTimeout` and `completeOnTimeout` methods. If the time elapses then the next stage will be invoked on the thread used to implement timeouts.

Comment: @Slaw I updated the question with an example. Maybe you can look or know about the subtle differences between the two versions..

Comment: In my opinion, the design of your code, or at least the example you provide, indicates using `Phaser` would be more appropriate. Use `CompletableFuture` if you want to chain different actions together based on the result of the previous action in an asynchronous manner. That said, `Phaser` would seem to be designed for something more sophisticated than your example suggests. Why not use `CountDownLatch`?

Comment: Thanks. `CoundDownLatch` would require to handle it within try..catch..clause..`Phaser` is less code in compare to `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: However, one benefit of CompletableFuture is that I can set the return type directly within .complete() so if I want to return a value, then CompletableFuture is less code in compare to Phaser. I run a benchmark and I cannot see any speed differences between using Phaser or CompletableFuture..so I think, there is no difference when it comes to speed performance. However, I think for blocking code, Phaser and CoundDownLatch is more appropriate and lightweight than CompletableFuture.