# CompletableFuture and Thread.currentThread().interrupt()

Tags: java

I have a `CompletableFuture` method with a timeout:

```
public List<User> findUsers() {
final CompletableFuture<List<User>> future = new CompletableFuture<>(); 

// code with future.complete(users);
...

try {
    return future.get(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
    }
}
```

And another method:

```
public List<Task> findTasks() {
    final CompletableFuture<List<Task>> future = new CompletableFuture<>(); 

    // code with future.complete(task);
    ...

    try {
    return future.get(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
    }
}
```

When I execute `find()` (I do not want to chain the both `CompletableFutures`):

```
void find(){
    // if this throws a timeout exception and interrupts its thread..
    findUsers();
    // ..then this will immediately throw java.lang.InterruptedException
    findTasks();
}
```

and `findUsers()` throws a timeout exception and interrupts the thread because of its catch-clause, then the `findTasks()` throws this error:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:385)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2093)
```

If I use

```
public List<Task> findTasks() {
    final CompletableFuture<List<Task>> future = new CompletableFuture<>(); 

    // code with future.complete(task);
    ...
    return future.join();
}
```

instead it works without error. However, how can I make it to work with `future.get()` and timeouts on both methods?

Comment: What if you use `catch (ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) { e.printStackTrace(); return null; } catch (InterruptedException e) { Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); e.printStackTrace(); return null; }`?

Comment: In other words, why are you interrupting the thread when you catch `ExecutionException` or `TimeoutException`? Normally one only (re)interrupts a thread after catching an `InterruptedException` because the thread's interrupt status is cleared before that exception is thrown. This allows subsequent code to react to an interrupt if needed. This depends on your design though; if you don't need the subsequent code to react to the interrupt, don't re-interrupt the thread.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your question and also why do you want to call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` ?

Comment: @Deadpool I must call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` within an `InterruptedException` or?

Comment: @Slaw I must catch InterruptedException when using future.get(). Without I get  a compiler error: `Unhandled exception type InterruptedException`.

Comment: I'm not asking why you're catching `InterruptedException`. I'm asking why you're re-interrupting the thread when catching exceptions _other than_ `InterruptedException`.

Comment: @Slaw oh yes, you are right. I now use Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); only within InterruptedException and it works.

Comment: About the other question: do you really need to re-interrupt the thread, even after catching an InterruptedException? I really dont know. I learned it to always put `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` within the catch of an `InterruptedException`. Is this wrong?

Comment: When using the above code with `CountDownLatch` or `Phaser` instead of `CompletableFuture` then it works without any errors even if `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` is called and (wrongly) placed within the catch clause of a `TimeoutException`. So there is something different in the behaviour of `CompletableFuture` in compare to the thread execution model of `CoundDownLatch` or `Phaser`. I dont know if this is better or not and I dont know the subtle differences which leads to this.

Comment: Honestly, you should not be calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` at all.  Interrupts do not happen by accident.  If someone interrupts your method, it means they explicitly want you to *stop what you’re doing* and exit as cleanly as possible.  For this reason, it is almost never correct to catch InterruptedException.  Remove it from your `catch` blocks, and add `throws InterruptedException` to the findUsers, findTasks, and find methods.  If you ignore interrupts, your code is a rogue thread that cannot be stopped.

Comment: @VGR I dont like the idea to never call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` The `throws InterruptedException` shifts it only to another place where it must be handled. It is better to handle it in the causing method.

Comment: That is literally the opposite of what you should do.  Your method is not qualified to handle it.  You are incapable of doing anything other than printing its stack trace and suppressing it.  Let the caller decide what the proper course of action is, if the thread is interrupted.  (Imagine if the InputStream.read method did not have `throws IOException` and you had no way to know whether a read failed or succeeded.)

Comment: Ok got it. Good example with `IOException`. Thanks.